# Set Listview ID from an ID Attribute from a MySQL Connection

Tags: android, mysql, listview

i am at the beginning to learn java and androd programming and I hope you can help me.

i want to set an id on a listview element. With this id I want to change my activity. The id should be the id which, also stand in a mysql database.

My Connection to the mysql Database is working. I have all information in an array and each listelement show following information "Name ID: 1". The onclick listener works also.

But how can i set the id to the listview? How how can i get the id information from the ArrayAdapter adapter?

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    if(result.equals("") == true || result.length() == 0 || result.equals("") == true || result == "|"){
        System.out.println("Hallo Welt!");

        result = "In der Datenbank gibt es keine Kategorie!";

    }


    // Senkrechter Strich entfernen
    String[] arr = result.split("\\|");
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter (this.context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
    this.list.setAdapter(adapter);

    //TODO Onclick Listener
    this.list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(context,  "my id to pass along the subview is " + position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}
```

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this give you an idea

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("ID", YourAdapter.YourItems.get(position).getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment... But I don´t know which I should set for "YourAdapter" and "YourItems"...Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: I tested it with a string and this function - but with "YourAdapter.YourItems.get(position).getId())" doesn´t function.^^